# Creating a log file via batch from multiple pc's (rows + columns)

Tags: windows, batch-file, tabs, cmd

I've been trying to get a nicely formatted log file for the render pc's that we're keeping, but I'm having some problems with it.

The setup: 2 (and later 6+) pc's that restart each morning between 8.00 am and 8.30 am.
On each pc there is a batch file that writes to the network server to log that it has restarted.

The text in the log file is a simple setup for how I want it structured:
<2 tabs> Comet <2 tabs> Vixen <2 tabs> Cupid <2 tabs> Dasher <2 tabs> Etc

The code on the first render pc:

```
<nul set /p ".=%date%   %time%">> \\no-s-05\Bram\_renderfarm.log
```

This way, the batch file will not create a new line when it has inputted its information.

The following machines will just have to add 2 tabs and their own time, and this is where I'm having a hard time, when they run the code:

```
<nul set /p ".=     %time%">> \\no-s-05\Bram\_renderfarm.log
```

For some reason I can't get it to add tabs. I was able to just add tabs before when I was closing the loop (letting it start on a new line) when I had just 2 pc's running a batch with the code:

```
echo        %time% >> "\\no-s-05\Bram\_renderfarm.log"
```

But I would like all pc's to add to their line with tabs before the last batch closes the file, which I can't seem to make it work.

I hope that what I told is clear, of course I'll also try to figure this out by myself but if anyone else has a solution, it would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: Can at least a reason be given for the downvotes? I've looked around but I can't find a solution for this problem so posting it here isn't a bad choice in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `set /P ...` command: it eliminate any control characters and spaces that appear *before* the first Ascii character in the prompt. There is no way to avoid this point.

However, the solution is simple: put the tabs *after* the data in each posterior `set /P` command. The only drawback is that the lines will end in two tabs.

First render pc:

```
<nul set /p ".=%date%   %time%   ">> \\no-s-05\Bram\_renderfarm.log
```

Following machines:

```
<nul set /p ".=%time%     ">> \\no-s-05\Bram\_renderfarm.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also found out that going with another approach (using a .csv file) is also possible, although excel does like messing with the numbers so I do like using Anacini's answer more.

The first pc would use the following code:

```
<nul set /p ".=%date%; %time%">> \\no-s-05\Bram\_renderfarm.csv
```

All but the last pc would use this line:

```
<nul set /p ".=; %time%">> \\no-s-05\Bram\_renderfarm.csv
```

And the last pc would use the following lines:

```
<nul set /p ".=; %time%">> \\no-s-05\Bram\_renderfarm.csv
echo.>> "\\no-s-05\Bram\_renderfarm.csv"
```

I'm using spaces in front of %time% to make sure excel keeps the original import instead of its own interpretation of the numbers.

The end result would look somewhat like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8572rjgwtqu55r/log_csv.png